# 59Hz option gone from Intel driver settings

Tags: drivers, resolution, hdmi, refresh-rate

With the new UI update to the Intel Graphics Control Panel, the 59Hz option for my second monitor is gone. 60Hz makes it report the wrong resolution which results in unwanted scaling and blurring of the image.

How can I fix this?

Intel HD 4000 + HDMI 1.4

Comment: I would roll back the driver since you say it was introduced in the current driver, the previous drive, should work without a problem.

Comment: I can't roll back the driver since it uses the old control panel. Recently Windows 8.1 is not allowing me to install the old control panel, when I forced it just crashed. btw, this update was a few months ago, my monitor power cable was broken at that time.

Comment: Need specific driver revision numbers.  If the previous release work at some point you should be able to install it.  Your question is not clear, if the problem is caused by the new drivers and the old control panel crash I would install just the driver and skip the installation of the control panel.

Comment: Current driver v10.18.10.3621 5/17/2014 (latest).

Comment: On fresh windows 8.1 I could install the drivers that came with the old control panel ui that had the 59hz option. 2 months ago there was an update for windows 8.1 and (after that update?) Intel forced updated their control panel to this modern ui wannabe, which doesn't have the 59hz option.

Comment: Now I can't install the old stuff without uninstalling windows updates.

Comment: Which update caused this behavior?  Which updates would need to be uninstalled.  I am not exactly sure what the question is, the new drivers are limited, you don't HAVE to install the intel control panel ( I have a Haswell CPU I should know )

Comment: I'm not really sure which update I need to uninstall, would have to check for dates and try, but I need intel to output the video signal at 59hz and this option is not there anymore. This is really frustrating since every forum post I read people are stuck at 59hz and want 60hz, but it's the opposite for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out, there's a custom resolution option in the Intel graphics control panel. I just added a 1280x800 resolution with 59Hz refresh rate and now when I choose that resolution, there's also 59Hz option alongside 60Hz.